# use nested loops in match-mode

Tags: math-mode, loops

I want use loop-variable in matrices. `\loop` and `\foreach` not worked in math-mode (and in matrices also), `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` worked only in one level:

```
\begin{equation}
A =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \m in {1,...,3}
  {
        a_{\m,1} &
  }
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

but nested loops not worked:

```
\begin{equation}
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \m in {1,...,3}
{
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \n in {1,...,3}
    {
        a_{\m,\n} &
    } \\
}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a different approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\formalmatrix}{mmm}
 {% #1 = letter, #2 = rows, #3 = columns
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #2 }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #3 - 1 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_adel_formalmatrix_tl { #1\sb{##1,####1} & }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_adel_formalmatrix_tl { #1\sb{##1,#3} \\ }
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_adel_formalmatrix_tl
  \end{bmatrix}
 }
\tl_new:N \l_adel_formalmatrix_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\formalmatrix{a}{2}{3}
\qquad
\formalmatrix{b}{4}{2}
\qquad
\formalmatrix{c}{4}{1}
\qquad
\formalmatrix{d}{1}{4}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]